# How to set `sf::Drawable` positions sfml

Tags: c++, c++14, sfml

I'm trying to declare a `sf::Drawable *` property inside my class body.

the code i already wrote:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

class View{
protected:
    sf::Drawable *view;
};
```

and inside the class constructor, I want to use the `view` properties:

```
class View{
public:
    View(){ view->...}
protected:
    sf::Drawable *view;
}
```

but I cannot access any of the `sf::Drawable` methods.
I get the `No member named 'setPosition' in 'sf::Drawable'` warning from IDE.

the only code suggestion i get from code completer is:

`draw(RenderTarget& target, RenderStates states)`

Comment: `sf::Drawable` is an abstract class that has only a virtual dtor, and a virtual `draw` method (no `setPosition` or any other). See: https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Drawable.php.

Comment: @wohlstad so how can I set its position? I need to use sf::Drawable so that later on i can use it for both `sf::RectangleShape` and `sf::Sprite`

Comment: @SalehSoleymani I am actually not familiar with SFML. The info I posted came up in a google search. You can try to use `dynamic_cast` to cast `sf::Drawable` to any of those derived classes you are interetsed in. However - the usage of `dynamic_cast` is usually discouraged as it can be avoided with an improved design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, `sf::Drawable` doesn't have a `setPosition` method. You could instead use [`sf::Transformable*`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Transformable.php), which does have `setPosition`.

If you **need** to have drawable properties, then...

1. If all your items are either shapes/sprites/texts, consider walking down the inheritance chain and use `sf::Shape`, `sf::Sprite`, or `sf::Text`.
2. Make a separate class for each (`ShapeView`, `SpriteView`, `TextView`).
3. Use `dynamic_cast`, as suggested by TheMedicineSeller. But this will incur a small runtime cost.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the positions of `view` inside the constructor of `View()` as `sf::Drawable` is a purely Abstract class that is meant only for inheritance.

One way to overcome this is by casting between the derived times at runtime but this method is definitely not recommended and can get ugly.

Another is to have the `setPosition()` function as `virtual` and consider a separate class say `RectangleView` which inherits the Base `View` class which implements the position setting

```
class View {
  protected:
    sf::Drawable* view;
    virtual void SetPosition() = 0;
};

class RectangleView : public View {
  public:
   SetPosition();
};
```

If u ask me, id consider whatever you are trying to do as a bit of overengineering and would advise to not using abstact classes and virtual functions at all for this purpose. Just have specific classes and functions for your sprites and rects.